# How to add to the end of lines containing a pattern with sed or awk?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Here is example file:

```
somestuff...
all: thing otherthing
some other stuff
```

What I want to do is to add to the line that starts with `all:` like this:

```
somestuff...
all: thing otherthing anotherthing
some other stuff
```

Answer (score 189, accepted):

This works for me

```
sed '/^all:/ s/$/ anotherthing/' file
```

The first part is a pattern to find and the second part is an ordinary sed's substitution using `$` for the end of a line.

If you want to change the file during the process, use `-i` option

```
sed -i '/^all:/ s/$/ anotherthing/' file
```

Or you can redirect it to another file

```
sed '/^all:/ s/$/ anotherthing/' file > output
```

Comment: Just adding something leads to a new line, replace is the right way.

Comment: On Mac OSX, for the `-i` option, I had to do like: `sed -i '' -e '/^all:/ s/$/ anotherthing/' file`

Answer (score 19):

You can append the text to `$0` in awk if it matches the condition:

```
awk '/^all:/ {$0=$0" anotherthing"} 1' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/patt/ {...}` if the line matches the pattern given by `patt`, then perform the actions described within `{}`.
- In this case: `/^all:/ {$0=$0" anotherthing"}` if the line starts (represented by `^`) with `all:`, then append `anotherthing` to the line.
- `1` as a true condition, triggers the default action of `awk`: print the current line (`print $0`). This will happen always, so it will either print the original line or the modified one.

#### Test

For your given input it returns:

```
somestuff...
all: thing otherthing anotherthing
some other stuff
```

Note you could also provide the text to append in a variable:

```
$ awk -v mytext=" EXTRA TEXT" '/^all:/ {$0=$0mytext} 1' file
somestuff...
all: thing otherthing EXTRA TEXT
some other stuff
```

Comment: On Solaris you will get the error: `awk: can't set $0`

Comment: @ceving then you can use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` which is the "good" awk.

Answer (score 10):

This should work for you

```
sed -e 's_^all: .*_& anotherthing_'
```

Using s command (substitute) you can search for a line which satisfies a regular expression. In the command above, `&` stands for the matched string.

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 9):

Here is another simple solution using sed.

```
$ sed -i 's/all.*/& anotherthing/g' filename.txt
```

Explanation:

all.* means all lines started with 'all'.

& represent the match (ie the complete line that starts with 'all')

then sed replace the former with the later and appends the ' anotherthing' word

Answer (score 6):

In bash:

```
while read -r line ; do
    [[ $line == all:* ]] && line+=" anotherthing"
    echo "$line"
done < filename
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution with awk:

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /^all/) print $0, "anotherthing"; else print $0}' file
```

Simply: if the row starts with `all` print the row plus "anotherthing", else print just the row.

Comment: You can shorten that to: `awk '$1=="all:" {$(NF+1)="anotherthing"} 1'`

Comment: @Prometheus, an awk script is composed of `condition {actions}` pairs. If the `condition` is omitted, the actions are performed for every record. If the `{actions}` are omitted, and the condition evaluates to *true* (which is the case for the number `1`) then the default action is to print the current record.