# sed: test for $pattern in $line before adding it

Tags: bash, sed, redhat

Several examples exist of how to use sed to add text to the end of a line based on matching a general pattern. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591744/add-to-the-end-of-a-line-containing-a-pattern-with-sed-or-awk).

In that example, the poster starts with

```
somestuff...
all: thing otherthing
some other stuff
```

and wants to add to the end of `all:`, like this:

```
somestuff...
all: thing otherthing anotherthing
some other stuff
```

All well and good. But, what happens if `anotherthing` is already there?!

I'd like to find the line starting with `all:`, *test for the existence of* `anotherthing`, and *only* add it if it is missing from the line.

How might I do that?

My specific case is testing `kernel` lines in `grub.conf` for the existence of `boot=` and `fips=1`, and adding either or both of those arguments *only if* they're not already in the line. (I want the search/add to be [idempotent](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^all:/!b;/anotherthing/!s/$/ anotherthing/' file
```

Disrequard any lines not starting with `all:` and only substitute lines that do not contain `anotherthing`.

Answer (score 2):

Skip lines with anotherthing and add it to the remaining lines starting with `all:`

```
sed '/anotherthing/!s/^all:.*$/& anotherthing/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` to check for existence of the given string and append it only if it is not there:

```
awk -v s='anotherthing' '/^all:/ && $0 !~ s "$" { $0 = $0 OFS s } 1' file
```