# How to search for lines beginning with a string, and add a string to its end in Sed?

Tags: sed, grep

On the Unix command line, I want to search for a string "Sample_string" at the beginning of a line in a file, and add a ";" at the end of the line in the file.

This would need to be an in-place edit, affecting a few dozen files in a particular directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, it is always great to show us some sample of Inputs and output in CODE TAGS even it is a simple query too. Also try to search solutions on site too, you may get plenty of help, cheers :)

Comment: see also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add to the end of a line containing a pattern - with sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591744/add-to-the-end-of-a-line-containing-a-pattern-with-sed-or-awk)

Comment: found the above link as first online search result for `sed search beginning add string at end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `sed` may help you on same:

```
sed '/^Sample_string/s/$/;/' Input_file
```

Comment: it was almost there. I had to add a -i at the beginning, so it actually needed to be written out as:                                                                                                   
                                    sed -i '/^Sample_string/s/$/;/' Input_file

Comment: Thanks bhai, you actually did a great job, and yes you're right, I could've been a little clearer. :)