# sed add id number at the end of each line

Tags: linux, sed

So I have a file where each line starts with a number from 1 to 9999 followed by user info like this: [inputfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLA1n.png). My question is how I can add the END of line a text string in format: ",C(numberID)" where "numberID" is the number at the start of the line.

I tried this answer from [this related question of how to write to the end of line containing a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591744/how-to-add-to-the-end-of-lines-containing-a-pattern-with-sed-or-awk):

**sed '/^[0-9],/ s/$/ ,C/' employees2.txt**

The [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORPoB.png) shows that the code works fine since it finds only lines starting with 1 digit number and add to the end of these line a ",C" string. However, what I want is to add a number after that ",C" so I tried this:

**sed '/^([0-9],)/ s/$/,C\1' employees2.txt**

This causes an error: *sed: 1: "/^([0-9],)/ s/$/,C\1": \1 not defined in the RE*

My expecting output will be something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggReD.png).

Comment: Then use `sed -E 's/^([0-9]),.*/&,C\1/' employees2.txt`

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/^([0-9]),.*/&,C\1/' employees2.txt  # POSIX ERE
sed 's/^\([0-9]\),.*/&,C\1/' employees2.txt   # POSIX BRE
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - POSIX ERE syntax enabled
- `^([0-9]),.*` - matches start of string, captures one digit into Group 1, then matches a comma and then any text till end of string (in POSIX BRE, you need to escape the capturing parentheses)
- `&,C\1` - replaces matched line with itself + `,C` and the digit from Group 1.

Comment: It works. thank you for your explanation. it's very clear !